# Xamarin.Android: When I create a button programmatically, why does it have a margin?

Tags: xamarin.android, android-button

EDIT: I think I figured it out. It was the background in the xml that was causing the difference.

Q:

I'm trying to add buttons to my app dynamically. (I need to create 1-6 buttons)

When I try to create a button in XML (to test the appearance), it looks like this:

[Buttons created in XML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M5gPI.png)

Here's the xml I used to create that:

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
    android:text="add button"
/>

<Button
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="100dp"
  android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
  android:text="add button"
  android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
  android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
/>
```

But when I try to create it programmatically, the buttons have a margin on the sides and they look a bit raised up.

How do I get then programmatic buttons to look the same as the XML buttons?

Is there some extra styling happening somewhere?

[Dynamically created buttons (below XML buttons)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jFPb7.png)

Here's the code I used to create the buttons dynamically:

```
var button = new Button(this);

var height = Utility.DpToPx(this, 100);
var width = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MatchParent;

var layoutParameters = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(width, height);
button.LayoutParameters = layoutParameters;
button.Text = "Test";
```

EDIT:
I think I figured it out. It's the background that I put in the xml that is causing the different effect:

```
android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
```

Comment: It seems that you have solved your issue by yourself, please post one reply and mark your reply as answer, it is beneficial to other community that encounter the same issue, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My confusion was caused by the fact that I did not add a background color to the buttons that I created programatically. That is why the appearances were different.